# URL rewrite to use relative path to image in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, rex

On my website, the images is using the full path e.g.  `mydomain.com/images/house.jpg` however I want to use the relative path `/images/house.jpg`

My question, how can I add a .htaccess rule to rewrite from full path to relative path?

Comment: That's not "URL rewriting". You can't do what you are asking with `.htaccess` (well, you kind of can with mod_substitute, but I wouldn't). You need to change your HTML source. What are you referring to with the "rex" tag? (Perhaps you meant "regex"?)